# XSL-FO Ignore the last page break but how?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

another question for the XSL-FO guys… 
Well I found out how do to a page break with

```
<fo:block page-break-after="always"> </fo:block>
```

This is working fine, but it adds me an empty page at the end of the document. I also tried it with “before” bit without success and “auto” well this is not what I am searching. 
Is there a possibility to count the breaks, or do the breaks until the last page and remove the last break or something like that. I found nothing on the reference, but maybe i`m searching for the wrong thing. Thanks in advance

```
http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#page-break-inside
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in your XSLT.  Instead of `<fo:block page-break-after="always"> </fo:block>`, you can do:

```
<fo:block>
  <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
    <xsl:attribute name="page-break-after">always</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
</fo:block>
```

This assumes that in your XSLT you're selecting all of the elements/attributes that produce the `fo:block` and processing them in one go (i.e., so they are all part of the same context so that the last one really is in the `last()` position).  If not, you'd have to find some other way for determining when to not generate the `page-break-after` attribute.

(Note that `page-break-after` is a shorthand for `break-after="page"`.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#page-break-after)